# Scaling Object in blender to real life dimension, makes it look small in the Blender Default cam

Tags: camera, scale, dimensions

I am making a vaguely accurate stadium. and the  boundaries of the ground are 0.200mtr in length per object of the array, is looking so small in the camera and perspective view. It wont even match the size of cricket 07 game -if that game was based on real life dimensions.

The boundaries from this angle of the camera dont often look so small in real life.

I think im having the ant man problem, where the object is small but the camera is not really built for the atomic scale perspective. I dont think this is a zoom in zoom out problem. Can anybody help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know where you got the dimensions from, of course 0.2 m = 20 cm is small compared to a stadium. And if I look at the reference image, if I suppose every repetition of text was a new object, then they are much longer than the player's foot on the ground. And I guess most player's have feet much longer than 20 cm. Also the noise on your grass texture makes it look as if you're much closer - you cannot see such noise detail on the reference. So if you were much closer to the grass, this also suggests the objects are smaller. But maybe you just need to add a player object to relate to.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are erroneously moving a decimal place. One meter is about how far you pace with each step. 0.2 meters, as a commenter said, is shorter than the average human foot: just under eight inches.

The boundaries are probably meant to be 2 meters long.